# Google play store is missing after installing Cyanogenmod 12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-play-store, samsung-apps

I installed CyanogenMod 12.1 to my galaxy S2(GT-I9100) along with gapps. (Later I tried the same with different gapps too) and everything went good, I successfully installed both zip from CWM 6.0.4.x.

But after I switch on my phone, after all initial steps, I noticed Google Play app is missing, all other gapps are present.

I have used same gapps file for installing in Galaxy note (GT-N7000) along with CyanogenMod 12.1 and Google play store is present

This is first time I'm facing these kind of issue with CyanogenMod installation.

Anybody can help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to wipe system partition. I just performed factory reset and wiped dalvik cache.
After wiping these and installing gapps again worked for me.